# How to negate the if binding?

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to achieve something like an "`ifnot`" binding, something like this:

```html
<div data-bind="ifnot: Categories"><p>No Categories available</p></div>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'category-template', foreach: Categories }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="category-template">
     <p data-bind="text: Title"></p>
</script>

<script>
     var self;

     function viewModel() {
          self = this;
          self.Categories = ko.observableArray([]);
     }

     ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

     var renderCategoryTemplate = function(data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               self.Categories.push({
                    Title: data[i].Title
               });
          }
     };
</script>
```

Is this possible? Or is there a better way to do this?

I can see the text **"No Categories available"** only for a second. But then it disappears. Any suggestions?

Comment: I updated my answer to give you an option to keep it from flickering.

Answer (score 2):

### Is there an ifnot binding

Yes there is an `ifnot` binding

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/ifnot-binding.html

From those docs:

```
<div data-bind="ifnot: someProperty">...</div>
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
<div data-bind="if: !someProperty()">...</div>
```

assuming that someProperty is observable and hence you need to invoke it as a function to obtain the current value.

### Why does it flicker?

The flickering you're seeing is because the dom renders first with that text before you run the knockout script and remove it.  To eliminate that you can set the text using knockout

```
<div data-bind="ifnot: Categories">
    <p data-bind:"text:'No Categories available'"></p>
</div>
```

That way the text won't be displayed before knockout runs, since KO is required to process it.  You can also now pull the message out and make it variable if desired.

Comment: Actually that isn't the same statement, as someProperty will evaluate to truthy if someProperty is an observable or not

Comment: ? I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, but in any case I was quoting from the docs.  EDIT: I see, I forgot to pull the last sentence in.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: The if bindings work off a value type of boolean, which evaluates to 'truthy' or 'falsy' depending on a few conditions.  'falsy' would represent any situation such as 'false', null, '', or undefined.  Truthy is anything else...

Comment: @ben336 tried your suggestion. the flickering isn't solved yet :(
Now I see nothing. but the page height first increases a bit and then again decreases.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it if not equal to

```
<div data-bind="if: !Categories()"><p>No Categories available</p></div>
```

This will evaluate to if there are no categories, then show this.

**Edit** If you don't want it to flicker do this -

```
<div data-bind="text: !Categories() ? 'There are no categories' : ''"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. but still I can't see the text. All the codes that you guys are put here should work. May be I'm doing something wrong here :(

Answer (score 0):

If I change the outer div to p tag than every answers works:

```
<p data-bind="ifnot: Categories">
    <p data-bind="text: 'No Categories available'"></p>
</p>
```

also works:

```
<p data-bind="if: !Categories()">
    <p data-bind="text: 'No Categories available'"></p>
</p>
```

Not sure why